# Django, change username form

Tags: python, django, user-management, django-forms

I'm trying to create a modelform to allow users to change their username. I'm trying to do this using FormView instead of UpdateView because I want to include other forms (user management functionality) in this view eventually.

Relevant forms.py:

```
    class FormHorizontalModelForm(forms.ModelForm)
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(FormHorizontalModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.helper = FormHelper()
            self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'

    class PlayerRenameForm(FormHorizontalModelForm):
        def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
            super(PlayerRenameForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)    
            self.helper.add_input(Submit('change_username', 'Change Username'))

        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ('username',)

        def save(self):
            pass # I figured this might be saving the object since this is inherited off ModelForm

        def form_valid(self, form):
            self.change_username(new_username = self.cleaned_data['username'])
            # self.send_email(new_username = self.cleaned_data['username'])

        def change_username(self, new_username):
            player = Player.objects.get(user = self.instance)
            self.instance.username = new_username
            self.instance.save()
            player.changed_username = True
            player.save()
```

views.py

```
    class AccountView(UserAuthenticationMixin, FormView):
        template_name = 'game/profile.html'
        success_url = '/accounts/'
        form_class = PlayerRenameForm
        form_class_two = CrispyPasswordSetForm
        form_class_three = CrispyPasswordChangeForm

        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(AccountView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            if 'form' not in context:
                context['form'] = self.form_class(user = self.request.user, data = (self.request.POST or None))
            if 'password_set_form' not in context:
                context['password_set_form'] = self.form_class_two(user = self.request.user, data = (self.request.POST or None))
            if 'password_change_form' not in context:
                context['password_change_form'] = self.form_class_three(user = self.request.user, data = (self.request.POST or None))
            return context

        def form_invalid(self, **kwargs):
            return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(**kwargs))

        def get_form(self, form_class):
            return form_class(user = self.request.user, **self.get_form_kwargs())

        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            if 'change_username' in request.POST:
                form = self.form_class(user = request.user, instance = request.user, data = self.request.POST)
                form_name = 'form'
            elif 'set_password' in request.POST:
                form = self.form_class_two(user = request.user, data = self.request.POST)
                form_name = 'password_set_form'
            elif 'change_password' in request.POST:
                form = self.form_class_three(user = request.user, data = self.request.POST)
                form_name = 'password_change_form'

            if form.is_valid():
                return self.form_valid(form)
            else:
                return self.form_invalid(**{form_name: form})
```

The form returns valid, and returns to success_url. I know for a fact that it is passing into the correct part of the post function since I have stripped away the other parts to ensure that was working.

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is the User object doesn't change.